# {body id="example" class="example2"}

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a question. Can I use id and class in body? I use them one to control in Jquery next to removeClass and addClass.

```
 $('#example2').hover(
 function() {
  $(this).removeClass('example2');
   $(this).addClass('example3');
 },
 function () {
   $(this).removeClass('example3');
   $(this).addClass('example2');
 } 
  );
```

Thank you for every answer!

Comment: id and class aren't a problem .... hover and unhover body is unconventional but it's your page. Not sure why you need 2 classes

Comment: If the matter is if you can, yes you can do it, don't think is the best but you can. Also seeing your code, wouldn't be better just to use [link](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) toggleClass instead ?

Comment: I did panel to change background in my site , just for training my skills jquery :P

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can use an ID on body or virtually any tag including script tags, style tags, meta tags...

Can simplify your hover a bit using `toggleClass()`

```
$('#example2').hover(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('example2 example3');
});
```

Note that you need one of these to be on the element to start.

`hover()` with only one function argument will work in both directions ... in and out. `toggleClass()` will add or removing depending on current state

Comment: ulala, so fast answer :D Thank  you i'm so happy :D i'm so newbie in js :P

Comment: when questions are well created and easy to understand you will always get fast interaction here

Comment: so i can ask  sometimes :PP?

Comment: not sure what that means but anyone can ask questions here about code